# What would .SelectMany(x => x) be in Sql

Tags: c#, sql-server

In C#, you can have the following code:

```
string[][] Stuff = new string[] { new string[] {"1", "2", "3"}, new string[] {"4", "5", "6"} };
string[] OneList = Stuff.SelectMany(x => x).ToArray();
```

So I was wondering, how can the same be done in sql?

In tables (Table 1 | Table 2):

| 1 | 4 |
| 2 | 5 |
| 3 | 6 |

End Result (Result of Tables 1 & 2 in same column):

| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |
| 4 |
| 5 |
| 6 |

So can this be done without using a temporary table?

Is it possible to do this in a simple sql statement?

Comment: What does your data source look like?  `SelectMany` is used to "flatten" a collection of collections, so it _may_ be possible in SQL but it would depend on the table structure(s).  There's not a specific function or operator that accomplishes that in general in SQL.

Comment: @DStanley: I have re-added the code snippet annotations, since the OP apparently used them to create the example tables. (Although ASCII tables might be better suited for this purpose.)

Comment: @Heinzi Good here-  I didn't realize that you could use code snippets to generate HTML tables that way.  Agree that ASCII tables would be more effective, though.

Comment: @Heinzi, I tried to use ASCII tables, but they did not work as I wanted it, and I was feeling lazy xD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since SQL Server does not support "nested" result sets, "flattening" them does not make sense either.

Your C# example takes two lists, wraps them, and then flattens them. This can actually be rewritten as a simple concatenation:

```
string[] OneList = Stuff[0].Concat(Stuff[1]).ToArray();
```

This operation---concatenating result sets---*is* supported by SQL Server. You can use `UNION ALL`:

```
SELECT column1 FROM table1
UNION ALL
SELECT column1 FROM table2
ORDER BY column1
```

Notes:

- `UNION ALL` keeps duplicates, `UNION` filters them.
- If `column1` has a different name in `table2`, your `ORDER BY` clause must use the column names from the first `SELECT` clause.

Comment: `UNION ALL` is more a `.Concat(...)`.  `.SelectMany(...)` is more `CROSS JOIN`/`CROSS APPLY`

Comment: @MatthewWhited: I don't think there is a direct equivalent, since SQL Server does not support nested recordsets. I have added a note that this is just a solution to the concrete example given.

Comment: True but it is closer and a `.Concat` will become a `UNION ALL` with EF.

Comment: @MatthewWhited: I have edited my answer to explain that his example basically *is* a (unnecessarily complex) way to write a concatenation.

Comment: Who knows... he many just need a recursive CTE or a numbers table.  Shame people don't say what they are trying to do versus show how they are doing it.

Comment: This is just a small sample, that approach won't work if you have a list of arrays, not just two.

Comment: @MatthewWhited It is more of a what if question, I was reading a bit on Linq and wondered what the SQL equivalent was. However, yes that approach will work, although not like I wanted it.

Comment: @JonathanCamilleri: Sure it will, you can use `UNION ALL` as often as you need.

Comment: @Heinzi I meant the C# version, sorry I was not as clear. The sql version I will check, it seems to be interesting. Unions and such are not quite my strong points.

Comment: The closest SQL would have is if you have a field you want to use as a  multi-value field.  (Exmaples may be data such as XML, JSON, CSV, Multi line text and so on.)  You can use table functions with `CROSS APPLY` on that field and get the same functionality as `.SelectMany(...)`